# VBA Update Dynamic Shape

Tags: vba, excel, shapes

I have a shape (which is actually a chart) that is generated dynamically. I however have problems updating this shape with VBA. My code looks as follows:

```
        .Sheets(sheet).Range("B12").value = NewReference
        Application.Calculate
        .Sheets(sheet).Shapes.Range(Array(NameOfShape)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        DoEvents
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
        PptSlide.Shapes.Paste
```

The shape is updated dynamically with a named range:

[Reference to name manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrJ2l.png)

The reference "=Bild" contains a formula to the range B12:

[Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/193sO.png)

In B12 the reference is dynamically depending on a certain input.

Overall, I can manually update the input and the shape changes as I want. If I however do updates with VBA and copy the shape, I do not get the updated shape. Any ideas?

[Excel 2013]